# Weighted interval scheduling, exponential time/ NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, intervals

According to this, a weighted schedule is considered NP-complete (not solve-able in polynomial time) if it has groups of 3 or more intervals:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling#NP-complete_when_some_groups_contain_3_or_more_intervals

But I don't understand the explanation at all. Why are 3 grouped intervals NP-complete, and why couldn't they be solved in polynomial time by some method? I'm not a math person, so the heavy math jargon lost me, a bit.

Comment: The title does not mention groups but your question does. Just to clarify (sorry if this was already obvious to you): the problem is NP-Hard when intervals are partitioned into groups, and groups are allowed to contain at east $3$ intervals. Also, we currently do not know whether group interval scheduling can be solved in polynomial time by some method, but if such a method were to existed, it would imply that P=NP.

Comment: Schedules are not NP-complete; problems are NP-complete.  I suggest that you [edit] your post to use language accurately.  This is the first step towards thinking clearly.